# Openlayers 3.10.1 bind Overlay to moving feature

Tags: openlayers

In my map I'm tracking vehicle locations. If a vehicles is clicked a Overlay with additional informations is shown. How can I "bind" the Overlay to the vehicle location. I tried

```
feature.getGeometry().on(
            'propertychange', 
            function(propEvt) { 
                console.log('I'm here');
                var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
                var centerOfFeature = getCenterOfExtent(extent);
                popup.setPosition(centerOfFeature);  
            }, 
            feature.getGeometry());
```

But log message is not shown but the feature is still moving.

-- Rüdiger

Answer (score 1):

try to bind it to feature and not the geometry.

```
feature.on('change',function(e){
 console.log('Im here');
 var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
 var centerOfFeature = getCenterOfExtent(extent);
 popup.setPosition(centerOfFeature);  
});
```